# PDO: данные в таблицу не добавляются

Tags: php, pdo

Ошибка: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 in C:\OpenServer\domains\test\Addrab.php:70 Stack trace: #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\test\Addrab.php(70): PDO->query('INSERT INTO rab...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\domains\test\Addrab.php on line 70`

Отрывок кода

```
                    $db = Db::getConnection();
                    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
//проверяем наличие записи об этом работнике в базе данных
                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM rabotn WHERE fio = \''.$fio.'\' AND prof = \''.$prof.'\' AND stag = \''.$stag.'\' LIMIT 0,100';
                    $result = $db->query($sql);
//если запись есть – обновляем данные об окладе
                    $num = $result->rowCount();
                    if ($num !=0)
                    {
                        $row = $result->fetch();
                        $id = $row[0];
                        $sql="UPDATE rabotn SET oklad='$oklad' WHERE (id='$id')";
                        $result = $db->query($sql);
                        echo '<h2>Запись обновлена...Вы можете добавить новую</h2><br>'.$form;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql = 'INSERT INTO rabotn(id, fio, prof, stag, oklad) VALUES (\'\', \''.$fio.'\', \''.$prof.'\', \''.$stag.'\', \''.$oklad.'\');';
                        $result = $db->query($sql);
                        echo '<h2>Запись добавлена...Вы можете добавить новую</h2><br>'.$form;
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

line 69-70 -

```
               $sql = 'INSERT INTO rabotn(id, fio, prof, stag, oklad) VALUES (\'\', \''.$fio.'\', \''.$prof.'\', \''.$stag.'\', \''.$oklad.'\');';
                $result = $db->query($sql);
```

структура таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В команде `INSERT INTO rabotn` не передано значение колонки id. Уберите её из этой SQL-команды.

Comment: И пожалуйста, никогда не составляйте SQL-запросы склеиванием различных строк. Это приводит к [уязвимостям](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Внедрение_SQL-кода). Используйте [подготовленные запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php) с параметрами. По последней ссылке изучите примеры с bindParam методом.